# Get particular information from a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the value of name from fstr using RegEx in Python. I tried as below, but couldn't find the intended result.

Any help will be highly appreciaaed.

```
fstr = "MCode=1,FCode=1,Name=XYZ,Extra=whatever" #",Extra=whatever" this portion is optional
myobj = re.search( r'(.*?),Name(.*?),*(.*)', fstr, re.M|re.I)
print(myobj.group(2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import re

fstr = "MCode=1,FCode=1,Name=XYZ,Extra=whatever"

myobj = re.search( r'Name=([^,]+)', fstr, re.M|re.I)

>>> print myobj.group(1)
XYZ
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not believe, but the actual problem was `,*`, in your regular expression. It makes matching `,` optional. So, the second capturing group in your regex matches nothing (`.*?` means match between zero to unlimited and match lazily) and it checks the next item `,*`, it also means match `,` zero or more times. So it matches zero times and the last capturing groups matches the rest of the string.

If you want to fix your RegEx, you can simply remove the `*` after the comma, like this

```
myobj = re.search( r'(.*?),Name(.*?),(.*)', fstr, re.I)
print(myobj.group(2))
# =XYZ
```

[Online RegEx demo (with the mistake)](http://regex101.com/r/rJ9wM8)

[Online RegEx demo (after fixing it)](http://regex101.com/r/vA9dW9)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/a2ifBrcZ1ElqD4In)

But as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23385729/1903116) shows, you don't have to create additional capture groups.

BTW, I like to use RegEx only when it is particularly needed. In this case, I would have solved it, without RegEx, like this

```
fstr = "MCode=1,FCode=1,Name=XYZ,Extra=whatever"
d = dict(item.split("=") for item in fstr.split(","))
# {'FCode': '1', 'Extra': 'whatever', 'Name': 'XYZ', 'MCode': '1'}
```

Now that I have all the information, I can access them like this

```
print d["Name"]
# XYZ
```

Simple, huh? :-)

**Edit:** If you want to use the same regex for one million records, we can slightly improve the performance by precompiling the RegEx, like this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"Name=([^,]+)", re.I)
match = re.search(pattern, data)
if match:
    match.group(1)
```

Comment: @AbdullahFahim Check the other method I mentioned in the answer, you will love that (keeping fingers crossed) :-)

Comment: neat :) ... but which one you think is faster, btw? Coz in this method couple of splits are involved .. (the speed is the prime importance to me, coz my code is annoyingly a longer one) ..

Comment: @AbdullahFahim If you are going to access all the values, then its better to create a record like dictionary and you can get the values whenever you want. If its a one-time thing, then you can use either of them as per your comfort level.

Comment: thanks a lot .. new thing I learn ... btw, I just needed that Name part, others are not useful .. but I have to get that "Name" information for millions of entries in each hour ...

Comment: @AbdullahFahim Please check the updated answer, I just gave a suggestion which can boost the performance little bit, if you are going with the RegEx method to process million records.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
rule = re.compile(r"Name=(?P<Name>\w*),")
res = rule.search(fstr)
res.group("Name")
```